# What exactly is an anode/cathode?

Tags: electrostatics

Whenever I look for answers I find stuff about batteries and chemical reactions.

But in videos like [these about thermionic emission](https://youtu.be/qHPVGEY01qc?t=74) there suddenly is a positively charged anode ring which pulls the elctrons towards it. Surely, there are no chemical reactions there.

So...in this scenario what is such an anode ring? How is it created? Is there current flowing through it or something else done to it to charge it positively ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode or the page for anode should suffices. For the second part of your question the ring is kept at a potential to work as anode.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Could you maybe tell me how the ring is kept at a potential ?
And finally: If the ring is positively charged then yes first the electrons leaving the filament will be attracted towards it but once they pass the ring the will be pulled back towards the ring. So in the end....how is it helpful to use such rings ?

Comment: See the answer below which also clarifies that there is no charge on the electrode plus and minus refer to polarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion here is that the words cathode and anode have different implications depending on the circumstances they are being used to describe.

Loosely, a cathode just means a metallic connector in a circuit that is a source of free electrons, while an anode is another connector to which the electrons will flow if they get the chance (ie if there is a conducting medium between the cathode and the anode).

In batteries chemical processes cause a build up of electrons in one area and a shortage in another. The cathode, which is a conductor of electrons, is a piece of metal in contact with the area where there is a surplus of electrons, while the anode, which also is a conductor, is a piece of metal in contact with the area where there is a shortage. If you connect a circuit between the two terminals, electrons will leave the cathode and travel through the circuit to the anode. The movement of the electrons is the current.

You don't need a battery to create a surplus of electrons at a cathode and a shortage at an anode- you can use a generator, for example, in which magnetic fields are used to move the electrons about. In arc welding, for example, you typically use mains electricity and a transformer to create a high voltage at the tip of a welding rod (the cathode) which causes electrons to flow to the piece being welded (the anode), which is connected to the other terminal of the transformer.

Comment: Thank you very much! So what I understood is that we can create regions with a surplus or lack of electrons and then cathode is the one with the surplus and anode the one with the lack of electrons. Now as soon as we connect them a current will flow. The thing no one really talks about is that there are more than 1 way to create these regions of lack/surplus. One way is a chemical reaction but we can use generators for this aswell. That is big!

Could you maybe explain to me how such an anode ring is able to accelerate/pull electrons towards it as discussed in the video?

Comment: Yes. A vacuum is a conductor- electrons can pass through it freely, so it plays the role of a wire. if you connect a wire, or any conductor, between a cathode and an anode, electrons will leave the cathode and flow to the anode.

Comment: A Negative Ion is attracted to Anode is how I always remembered it...